# LD_PRELOAD error in chroot shell but working in normal shell

Tags: android, lib, chroot, ld-preload

I'm using an android system with Kali Nethunter chroot installed. When I try to use a program after LD_PRELOAD in chroot I get:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/system/lib/libfakeioctl.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

… but using the normal shell it doesn't show and its working perfectly.

I tried copying the **.so** file to different directories
I tried changing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` and `$LD_PRELOAD=`

After running `nexutil` command and loading the **.so** library the wireless interface should be in Monitor mode (using *iwconfig* to check).
In the normal shell this thing happens but in Kali chroot it doesn't.